# Check a div value and update a class in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, axios

It will be part of the app Dashboard. It will receive a number as a string from the API, this part is still to be implemented. Probably an `axios`call at the `onComponentDidMount`.

I want to set some number text in a specific color depending on its value. I am reading the number value at page load and `onChange`, then setting a bootstrap class. Im developing in Ionic with `React`.

```
this.state = {
    warningColor: true
}

componentDidMount() {
    var delayed: HTMLElement | null = document.querySelector("#delayed");
    if (delayed != null && delayed.textContent === "0") {
        this.setState({ warningColor: false })
    }
}

handleAlerts() {
    var delayed: HTMLElement | null = document.querySelector("#alert");
    if (delayed != null && delayed.textContent == "0") {
        this.setState({ warningColor: false })
    } else {
        this.setState({ warningColor: true })
    }
}

<div id="alert" className={"number " + (this.state.warningColor ? "text-warning" : "text-success")} onChange={this.handleAlerts}>0</div>
```

Is there a better/cleaner way to check the value and set the class in the `div`?

Comment: Where does the change happens ? Can't you set the value throw state ?                      ```this.state = {
  warningColor: true, alerVal:0
}``` and change the state on change ?

Comment: When is the number of alerts going to change? You have a static `0` in there; is some other part of the app going to do `alert.textContent = "X"`? and calling `onChange`? That's seems very inelegant; the number of alerts should get passed to the Component as prop.

Comment: The static value `0`, can't you manage that in the application state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React way, 1) avoid using querySelector and fetch values and 2) have your conditions in render method. How about some this like this. Hope this helps.

```
this.state = {
    aletText: 0
}

componentDidMount() {
// change state (alertText or other delayedText) if required
}

handleAlerts() {
// change state (alertText or other delayedText) if required
}

render() {
    const { alertText } = this.state;
    // if required with delayedText, store in state and add condition here
    var alertClass = "number " + (alertText !== 0 ? "text-warning" : "text-success") ;
    return (<div id="alert" className={alertClass} onChange={this.handleAlerts}>{alertText}</div>)
}
```